# mysql date format, inserting a dash

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to achieve this format **01/01/2011 - 12:30pm** for the date and time update into mysql how would I add in a dash and it my date format correct?

```
$sqlLD = "UPDATE ".$membtable." 
          SET m_lld= ".date("m/d/y g:i A")." 
          WHERE m_user='".$line['m_user']."'";

$resultLD = @mysql_query($sqlLD); //insert format 01/01/2011 - 12:30pm
```

**Solve error on my part code wasn't updating to server. only a simple dash was needed.**

Comment: Have you tried `date("m/d/y - g:i A")`?

Comment: @RowlandShaw thanks I just noticed my error, what I typed here isn't the same as in my code window. it wasn't updating when I saved, no wonder I didn't see a change. thanks.

Comment: Store like this you have take filed as varchar... its not allowed in datetime field...

Answer (score 0):

which **data type** are you using for the field **m_lld** . if you are using any data type like **date,datetime,etc** it will not be inserted because when you insert a *dash* into the input it will take the input as a string. So if you want to store the value as you said use **varchar** as a **datatype**

Answer (score -1):

Simply add it?

```
$sqlLD = "UPDATE ".$membtable." 
      SET m_lld='".date("m/d/y - g:i A")."' 
      WHERE m_user='".$line['m_user']."'";
```